# How to update Google Region Chart data dynamically upon drop-down selection using JSF & Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf

I have an application written in JSF/JEE 1.7 and deployed on Glassfish 4.0.

My use case is that when a user makes a selection from a drop-down list (select one menu in JSF), an associated Google Region Chart showed be displayed/refreshed. Subsequently, when the selection changes, the Google region chart should update itself.

Presenting my code below.

> Javascript code (inside the XHTML template for the page)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages' : [ 'corechart' ] });

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionChart);

  function drawRegionChart() {
      // Create the data table.
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [ 'State', 'Count' ],
          #{productProfileListController.regionChartData}
      ]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
        region: 'IN',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
        title:'Presence of product or service found in states',
        width: 640, 
        height: 480
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('region_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  }   
</script>
```

The place where the JSON gets passed from the bean is `#productProfileListController.regionChartData}` in the code above.

> JSF code (inside the same XHTML template)

```
<!-- Page section that allows the user to make a selection. -->
<div class="form-group">
  <h:outputLabel for="product-service" value="Please select Product or Service" styleClass="control-label" /><span style="color:red;">*</span>

  <!-- Dropdown list from which the user can make a selection. -->
  <h:selectOneMenu id="product-service" required="true" value="#{productProfileListController.product}" styleClass="form-control">
    <f:selectItems value="#{productListController.products}" var="product" itemValue="#{product}" 
                   itemLabel="#{productListController.getDisplayText(product)}"/>
    <f:converter converterId="domainConverter" />        
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{productProfileListController.valueChanged}" render="product-profile-panel" execute="@this" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <h:message for="product-service" styleClass="text-danger" />
</div> 

<!-- Page section that refreshes based on the user selection. -->
<h:panelGroup id="product-profile-panel" layout="block">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty productProfileListController.productProfileListByHSCode}" layout="block">
    <h2 class="page-header plain-header">
      <i class="icon-star icon-sm"></i> Presence in states across India
    </h2>

    <!-- Force the chart to be redrawn. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      drawRegionChart()
    </script>

    <!-- Container for the Google Region chart to be displayed. -->
    <div id="region_chart_div" style="width:80%;height:450px;"></div>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

> The JSF bean

```
class ProductBean {
    private String regionChartData;

    public void valueChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        // Determine the selected product.

        regionChartData = ... build data for the chart based on the selected product ...
    }

    public String getRegionChartData() {
        return regionChartData;
    }
}
```

On debugging I see that the method `valueChanged` gets called on change in dropdown list. It also sets `regionChartData` to the expected value. However, the `getRegionChartData` return `null` so that everytime the dropdown value changes, the map shows nothing because calling `drawRegionChart()` from the XHTML file returns `regionChartData` as `null`.

Can you please help in letting me know where is the issue here, and how the Google chart will get updated upon dropdown selection change?

Comment: You normally should start creating an [mcve] and then notice it has nothing to do with either javascript of google-maps but all to do with the basics of ajax and updating parts of the page. See the answer. Oh and debugging to see if the `getRegionChartData` is called in the update would have given more insight too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nowhere update the script that contains the `drawRegionChart()` function and `#{productProfileListController.regionChartData}`. This latter EL will not be called each time the javascript function is called as you seem to be expecting. It is only called when the part is (re) rendered. Put this script inside the

```
<h:panelGroup id="product-profile-panel" ...> </panelGroup>
```

which you **do** update in the ajax call and it will work. You could also just define a small javascript part with a variable so the amount of code to be updated is less and call the drawRegionChart() with that as a parameter.

Comment: If you see, I am calling the `drawRegionChart()` method here where you would see the comment as

`<!-- Force the chart to be redrawn. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      drawRegionChart()
    </script>`

It does call the JS Function but the `regionChartData` is NULL. 

Am I missing something that you are trying to say?

Comment: @DIM, the suggestion is that you move the whole `<script>...</script>` code within the panel (`<h:panelGroup id="product-profile-panel">`)that is refreshed on AJAX calls. That way, the JavaScript code will get rendered every time a valid selection is made, and will in turn make the server-side call.

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. I moved the entire method contents of `function drawRegionChart()` in the template XHTML under `<script> .. <script>` within the panel  `<h:panelGroup id="product-profile-panel">`.

Comment: Should work, I do things like that all the time. Did you check/debug the network traffic in the browser developer tool? And compare with https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=56160&sid=49c902cf70395914f97f084e84fcffe0, the 'solution' works there. So debug what is going on when you do have it in the panelGroup, or maybe the `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionChart);` is keeping an old 'handle' and should be moved inside it as well. (I mentioned to put the whole scrfipt thing inside or just a variable...)